# Заполнение родительского div дочерними divами

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, html

Есть один div, который растянут на всю ширину и высоту экрана. Необходимо заполнить этот div дочерними, квадратными, div'ами, чтобы с виду получилось аля сетка как в тетради в клетку. Прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужен вид *"тетрадь в клетку"*, то не обязательно заполнять страницу тысячами `<div>`-ов. Это легко делается с помощью  CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent, transparent 20px, #555 21px),
              repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 20px, #555 21px);
}
```